# Merge sort stops running

Tags: c, sorting, merge

So my problem is, when I try to run my merge sort algorithm, it writes the random array on screen but when it tries to write the sorted array, the program stops working. I've been trying find my error but no hope so far. Appreciate any help.

Here is my code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 300
#define INF 30000

void merge (int *A, int p, int q, int r){
     int i, j, k, n1 , n2 , *L, *R;

     n1 = q - p + 1;
     n2 = r - q;
     L = (int *) malloc (n1* sizeof (int ) + 1);
     R = (int *) malloc (n2* sizeof (int )) ;
     for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
         L[i] = A[p + i];
     }
     for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
         R[j] = A[q + 1 + j];
     }
     i = j = 0;
     L[n1] = R[n2] = INF ;

     for (k = p; k < r; k++) {
         if(L[i] <= R[j]){
                 A[k] = L[i];
                 i ++;
         }
         else{
              A[k] = R[j];
              j ++;
         }
     }
     free(L);
     free(R);
}

void mergesort (int *A, int p, int r){
     int q;
     if(r > (p + 1)){
          q = (p + r)/2;
          mergesort(A, p, q);
          mergesort(A, q + 1, r);
          merge(A, p, q, r);
     }
}

void sorting_merge(int *A, int n){
     mergesort (A, 0, LEN);
}

int main (){
    int i, *n;
    n = malloc ( sizeof (int )*LEN );
    srand (666) ;
    for (i = 0; i < LEN ; i++) {
        n[i] = rand() % 1000;
        printf ("%d ", n[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    sorting_merge(n, LEN);
    for (i = 0; i < LEN ; i++) {
        printf ("%d ", n[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    free (n);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should be more specific about the errors you encounter, and where they occur.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Well i tried to use the debugger on dev c++ but couldn't able to run it. ^^ After i changed "R = (int *) malloc (n2* sizeof (int )) ;" to "R = (int *) malloc (n2* sizeof (int ) + 1) ;" the program runs just fine but doesn't sort correctly. I think i messed something up...

Comment: `malloc (n2 sizeof (int ) + 1)` is not correct. Either `malloc((n2+1)*sizeof (int))` or `malloc(n2*sizeof(int) + sizeof(int))`.

Comment: After i changed like you suggested, program still runs but still giving an unsorted array at the end. I think i made a mistake on some function parameters.

Comment: what happens when r is <= p+1? I.E. the else of if(r > (p + 1)){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to

```
L = (int *) malloc((n1+1)* sizeof(int));
R = (int *) malloc((n2+1)* sizeof(int));

for (k = p; k <= r; k++) {//include r

if(r > p){

void sorting_merge(int *A, int n){//call sorting_merge(n, LEN); note LEN is out range
    mergesort (A, 0, n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`L[n1] = R[n2] = INF ;` accesses beyond the allocated memory. Your allocation should read

```
L = malloc((n1 + 1) * sizeof (int));
R = malloc((n2 + 1) * sizeof (int));
```

if you really want to access index `n1` and `n2`.

I haven't checked anything else, that was the first thing that sprang in my eyes.